# Фильтр списка из БД

Tags: python, django

Добрый день.
Есть модель с объектами.
Нужно вывести в шаблон список объектов отфильтровав по полю `zakaz_status`.
Пишу

```
k_z_1s = Zakaz.objects.filter(zakaz_status=1)
```

Но в тот же момент мне нужно вывести в шаблон эти объекты в обратном порядке(сейчас от первого до последнего, а нужно чтобы сверху отображался последний)
по идее

```
k_z_1s = Zakaz.objects.order_by('-zakaz_status')
```

но как мне во вьюхе обьеденить эти об фильтра? или есть какой-либо другой способ?
django 1.8  python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k_z_1s = Zakas.objects.filter(zakaz_status__exact=1).order_by('-zakaz_status')
```

Только мне непонятно, зачем упорядочивать выдачу по `zakaz_status`, если мы фильтруем по единственному значению этого поля?
Вообще фильтры объединяются именно так:

```
Model.objects.filter(...).filter(...).filter(...).order_by(...)
```

Вообще, `Model.objects.filter()` возвращает объект `QuerySet`, такой же, как `Model.object.all()`, и к нему применимы все эти методы типа `filter, order_by` и т.п.

Comment: по номеру заказа)) перепутал